# Tabulator, How to update only 1 cell of 1 row?

Tags: tabulator

In Tabulator, I need to update only 1 cell in a row, (stock price).
I have tried every combination of set, add, update and updateOrAdd Data.
Everytime it adds a new row when price updates, or just nothing happens.
Please help.

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle or show us what you have tried so far?  Here is an example of how to update data: https://jsfiddle.net/9n1szwgo/ as explained here: http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/update#alter-update

Answer (score 0):

you must have an [index](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/options#data) field in your data (the default is "id") to use the the various [update](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/update#alter-update) functions (to tell Tabulator which row you want to update). If you have the Row , then you can just use its [update](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/update#row)() (as it doesnt need an "id" field to know which row it is)